# Value does not fall within the expected range with GetServerVariableInternal

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am not sure why this error is happening but following the source code it is caused by `GetServerVariableInternal` with the value `IIS_WasUrlRewritten`.  Why is this happening and how can I stop it?  When I manually go to this page it never happens.  The `ThrowIfFailedHr` keeps throwing an error.

**Original Error**

```
Error in Path :/177359/2021-2022-abybl-regular-season/schedule
Raw Url :/177359/2021-2022-abybl-regular-season/schedule
Message :Value does not fall within the expected range.
Source :mscorlib
Stack Trace :   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String name)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.WasThisRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues)
   at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, String protocol, String hostName, String fragment, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues)
   at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.RouteUrl(String routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, String protocol, String hostName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.T4Extensions.Action(UrlHelper urlHelper, ActionResult result)
```

**WasThisRequestRewritten**

```
    private const string UrlWasRewrittenServerVar = "IIS_WasUrlRewritten";
            private const string UrlRewriterEnabledServerVar = "IIS_UrlRewriteModule";
    
            private object _lockObject = new object();
            private bool _urlRewriterIsTurnedOnValue;
            private volatile bool _urlRewriterIsTurnedOnCalculated = false;
    
            private static bool WasThisRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                NameValueCollection serverVars = httpContext.Request.ServerVariables;
                bool requestWasRewritten = (serverVars != null && serverVars[UrlWasRewrittenServerVar] != null);
                return requestWasRewritten;
            }

private string GetServerVariableInternal(string name) {
            IntPtr buffer;
            int bufLen;

            int retval = IIS.MgdGetServerVariableW(_context,
                                                   name,
                                                   out buffer,
                                                   out bufLen);

            Misc.ThrowIfFailedHr(retval);

            if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero) {
                return StringUtil.StringFromWCharPtr(buffer, bufLen);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Is this error happening locally? Or does this error occur only after publishing to iis?

Comment: This happened on the live production server, so not sure how to every debug this as it happens randomly.

Comment: you can try to debug the cause using IIS [Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210), this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.